# get string when trying to make a dynamic json list / array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to make a dynamic JSON array in PHP, however when I try to do so it returns **"Array"**. Here is the code I am currently using:

```
        <?php
        require '../../scripts/connect.php';    

    $array = '';
    if($result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM art") or die ($db->error)){
      if($count = $result->num_rows) {
             while($row = $result->fetch_object()){

        $array .= array(
            'title'    => $row->title,
            'image'     => "http://www.thewebsite.com/img/2.jpg",
            'rating'     => 7.7,
            'releaseYear'     => 2003,
            'genre'  => array(
                '0'        => $row->category,
                '1'        => $row->subcategory
            )
        );
       }
      }
     }

    echo json_encode($array);





    ?>
```

Can anyone suggest how I might go about fixing this?
And if anyone has suggestions about creating a dynamic JSON array, some help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your declaration of `$array` to be an array:

```
$array = array();
```

Then in your `while` loop, when you add the new array to `$array`, push it like this:

```
$array[] = array('title'=>$row->title, etc...)
```